# File uploader in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

How can identify input (type="file") id of fileupload while file uploading to server.

Let me explain in detail:

I have multiple file upload control on my page and different control save file on different folders like "Fileupload1" will save file on "Folder1" and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The `id` of an HTML element is **never** sent to the server when posting a form. As far as the `name` attribute is concerned you may loop through the [Request.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) collection. In ASP.NET MVC it more common to use action parameters. Example:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file3" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload files" />
</form>
```

and your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) 
{
    foreach (var file in files) 
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: I have multiple file upload to upload file on server then how can i identify the file to related input.
suggest if u have idea.

Comment: But it doesn't return and name of input

Answer (score 0):

As Darian points out, the ID isn't sent. But the name attribute is, so your file upload should be something like:

```
<input type="file" name="contactsFile" />
```

Which will let you use a method such as

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase contactsFile)
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access to any DOM element since ASP.NET MVC uses the FileCollectionModelBinder to create a collection of files. So what you receive in your controller won't have anything to do with the DOM. But the good thing is since it's a collection you can access the index of the file.

```
  <input type="file" name="files[0]" id="file1" />
  <input type="file" name="files[1]" id="file2" />
  <input type="file" name="files[2]" id="file3" />
```

Then if you need to upload files[0] to folder Y and files[1] to folder Z you can access the files collection index.

```
switch (index)
{
   case 0:
   // Upload to Y
   case 1:
   // Upload to Z
   default:
}
```